# ic_launcher.xml not being used as app icon

Tags: android, xml, appicon

I'm developing an Android app.

I'm trying to use ic_launcher.xml and ic_launcher_round.xml as app icons as I think that is the proper way?

Anyway, I have one png image, 108x108px, 32bit color. I use it in both ic_launcher and ic_launcher_round as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/app_icon" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

The code is the same for both xml files.

The problem is that on newer os versions (8.0+, round icons) it works well, but on earlier versions it doesn't (7.0, square icons) it doesn't work at all, and defaults to standard android icon.

I'm currently creating all images that I will use to replace ic_launcher.png in mipmaps, but aside from that can I do something else?

In manifest, I use them as:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

Comment: you should define ic_launcher for different screen sizes and place them in the corresponding folders - And dont place ic_launcher in drawable - you should use mipmap

Comment: I've created new images for all values, and it works ok. I accapted the answer with Image Assets because I plan to use them in the future, but not right now. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize your app's icon using Android Studio tools.

1. In the Project window, select the Android view.
2. Right-click the res folder and select New > Image Asset.

More: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to use at least 512x512 px images to generate launcher icons for app.

there is great online tool to generate launcher icons to fit all screens:

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

or you can use Android Studio's default tool to import your image and generate it anyway.

*(right click) -> New -> Image Asset*

Comment: 512x512px are used for the playstore listing. No need for the app itself as the default icon is 48x48dp.

Comment: you need better image quality to generate your launcher icons, their size will be 192x192,144x144, 96x96, 72x72, 48x48